# How to connect local pc database with my android application in phone?

Tags: android, database

I'm new to android programming. I need to develop an application which should save the data in my PC and not in the phone, say like to save some contacts directly in my PC from my phone. So I need some guidance for achieving this. Before that i want to know whether the above mentioned scenario is achievable or not.

Comment: Yes you can, you can retrieve contacts information and let say, saved it to sqlite database or sync to your local pc using server side scripting language like php.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to save the data on your phone then move it over to the PC. To move the data to the PC, there's a couple of approaches you could take:

- Simply copy the data via USB
- Run a web server on the PC and send the data over HTTP

Another flexible approach would be to push the data to a server on the internet. For example you could use a Google Account and one of the data APIs to send the data from the phone to your Google account. See the Google Spreadsheet API as an example:
http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/

Comment: Thanks first of all, you have mentioned two ways to achieve what I've asked, could you provide me some information about the second way.

Comment: You'd need to write a little web application that will accept requests from your phone. This means the phone needs to be able to see the IP address of the PC on your local WIFI network.  Then you phone app can use the HTTP Client in Android to send the data to the PC Web application.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this would be to create a web service that would accept the data from the phone in xml/json over the internet.

After receiving the data the PC can then save the data in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Could you please provide me some information about web service creation and how to link it with my android application.